# How to make an Exact Phrase text-search in MongoDB using variable (and node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find a list of mongoDB documents based on exact phrase search. I want to first store exact phrase in a **variable** and then search for it by using **text-search** query. So far I have I have built this and it works fine:

```
  const wordx = "coffee forest";
  SentenceModel.find({$text:{$search: wordx}}).then(function(records){
    res.send(records);
  });
```

However, when I want to adopt this for **exact phrase search** by using escape quotes, it doesn't work because it is a variable, not a string. Do you know how can I exact phrase search a variable? (Similar questions on this website do not have answers to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers or comment yet, but I found a solution and I am writing it here for everybody's benefit and future reference.

The solution includes new Javascript template literals (if you are using python, you can use format() method).

```
const wordx = "coffee forest";
const wordy = `\"${wordx}\"`;
SentenceModel.find({$text:{$search: wordy}}).then(function(records){
  res.send(records);
});
```